# Share a function across template instances

Tags: c++, templates

I would like to share a function across template instantiations, and wonder whether there's a way to do that.

_____ edit to clarify question _____

Lets look at the following example

```
#include <array>

template <unsigned int K>
class kd_tree
{
public:

    using kd_point = std::array<float, K>;

    bool isValid(const kd_point &kdPoint) const
    {
        for (unsigned i = 0; i < K; i++)
            if ( isnan(kdPoint[i]) ||
                 kdPoint[i] == numeric_limits<float>::infinity() ||
                 kdPoint[i] == -numeric_limits<float>::infinity() )
                return false;

        return true;
    }
};
```

for each value of K, a new value of isValid will be created that differs by nothing except the concrete value of K. It certainly doesn't need K to use kd_point's operator[]

Question is whether there's a way to take isValid out of the class and make it a function that accepts a kd_point & a K as parameters, and check the point, thus saving in executable size on multiple copies of it, e.g. one for K=2 & another for K=3.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I've understood the question, but could a factory like the following one solve the problem?

```
void fn() { }

template<void(*Function)()>
class C {
    C() = default;

public:
    static C<Function>* create() {
        return new C<Function>{};
    }
};

using CfnFactory = C<fn>;

int main() {
    C<fn> *c = CfnFactory::create();
}
```

Note that the example above applies well also with member functions, it's only a minimal example of a possible solution from which to start (of course, if I got the problem).

The idea is to inject in the factory the function to be used to create instances of your type, so that all of them will rely on the same function. This way you can also create multiple factories based on different functions and mix together the returned objects (the last point requires a base, non-template class, but it's quite easy to do).

In any case, I strongly suggest you to reduce the amount of code in your example to a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
It would help the reader and it will increase the chances to get a valid response.